# app icon for retina device

Tags: iphone, retina-display

My app's icon is named:

appicon57x57.png

This works great on simulator and device.  I don't have a retina device to test on.  But if I make a 114x114 version of my app icon and call it:

appicon57x57@2x.png

and put in in the same place as the other icon, will it show on the retina devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your `Info.plist` lists the app icon name as `appicon57x57` (as it should since you say it works), and you make sure to add the `appicon57x57@2x` version to your project (and its build target), then yes, Retina Display devices should detect the `appicon57x57@2x` version and load that one.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm having trouble with this, too. The Apple docs seem inconsistent about whether or not you include the .png extension.  I'll go experiment with that, but you might want to tweak your answer to address that issue.  [EDIT: removing the .png from my info.plist did, indeed, solve this for me.]

Comment: yep, that fixed it for me too. With the .png extension, it didn't find the @2x version